# Read input in NASM, and store it whole into a variable

Tags: variables, assembly, input, store

what is the method by which I can read the input of the user, say the input is "500"
then store this number in a variable?

The only method I know would be to store them character by character with possibly the need of register offsets.

Is there any other way, preferably storing the number directly?

i.e. something like:

`mov var1, inbuffer`

Details on environment:
`32 bit Assembly w/ DGJPP`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... DJGPP, that'd be dos I guess. Look into int 21h/0Ah (0Ah in `ah`). Or you might be better off with the readfile subfunction (3Fh ???) on stdin. Look it up in Ralf Brown's Interrupt list.

In any case, what you're going to get is the characters '5', '0', and '0' - 35h, 30h, 30h. It will take some processing to get the number 500 out of this. If you're reading numbers from left to right, zero up a register to use as "result so far". Read a character from your input buffer. If it's a valid decimal digit, subtract '0' to convert character to number, multiply "result so far" by ten, and add in your new number. Repeat until you run out of characters.